# javascript onmouseout works also on mouse over

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm trying to show/hide ***some*** of text in a button. 
the button is

```
<button id="SOS" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide();">
    <p>S.O.S</p>
    <div id="sos_left"> <?=$text_to_show_hide?></div>
</button>
```

and the javascript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show()
    {
        sos_left=document.getElementById('sos_left');
         alert("mouseover");
         sos_left.style.color = "red";
         sos_left.style.fontSize = "28";

    }
function hide(){

       sos_left=document.getElementById('sos_left');
       alert("mouseout");
       sos_left.style.color = "blue";
       sos_left.style.fontSize = "0";
}
</script>
```

the thing is that the mouse out alerts even when I'm mouse overing.

NOTE: I can't use jquery because the site is vbulletin based and I use this code on one of the templates.

Comment: Have your tried using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont hide anything..

use `display:none` to "remove" element, or `visibility:hidden` to hide element.

to "re-add" the element, use `display: block` or `visibility:visible`, if you used visibility attribute to hide.

try each both to see the difference.

another problem is,

you try to use `sos_left` as variable, but you didn't declare it as variable.

use `var sos_left` instead of.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `mouseover` and `mouseout` events bubble up, and this means that when your cursor enters and exits from elements that are descendants of your button, the event listener defined on the button is triggered too.

What you can do is to check if the element that generated the event is actually the `<button>` element. Fix the DOM like this:

```
<button id="SOS" onmouseover="show(event)" onmouseout="hide(event);">...
```

Then your JS code:

```
function show(e) {
    if ((e.target || e.srcElement).id !== "SOS") return;
    ...

function hide(e) {
    var tgt = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (tgt.id !== "SOS") return;
    // If the cursor enter in one of the descendants, mouseout is fired, but
    // we don't want to handle this
    if (tgt.contains) {
        if (tgt.contains(e.relatedTarget || e.toElement)) return;
    } else if (this.compareDocumentPosition)
        if (tgt.compareDocumentPosition(e.relatedTarget)
                & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS) return;
    ...
```

In Internet Explorer (and now in Opera too) there are these events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` that behave very similarly, but don't bubble up. For other browsers they're emulated in common frameworks like jQuery.

On a final note, I'd suggest you to use some more modern method to attach your event listeners than the traditional one. Plus, the way you define `sos_left` implies that it becomes a global variable. Use the keyword `var` in front of the definition.

Comment: That's almost correct ;) When "leaving" the button by moving the mouse over a children the `mouseout` will still be fired as the src of the event is the button [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJhr2/1/)

Comment: @Andreas Good point, I had this feeling that I was forgetting something. Fixing the code...

Answer (score 0):

That's because you apply the event to the `div` not the `button`. Try this:

```
sos_button=document.getElementById('SOS');
```

Comment: You're wrong ;) `<button id="SOS" onmouseover="show()" onmouseout="hide();">...</button>`